# Codeigniter with javascript

Tags: html, javascript, php, css

am working with codeigniter and trying to submit a form and then closing it with javascript…

i have a popup function…that i call from the parent page:

```
<a href = "javascript:popup('controller/method/variable', 'Click', '400', '400')">Click</a>
```

and here is the function:

```
function reject_popup(url, name, width, height){
    var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight / 2) - (height / 2));
    var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth / 2) - (width / 2));
    var features = "location=1, status=1, scrollbars=1, width=" + width + ", height=" + height + ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left;
  window.open(url, name, features);}
```

and it opens this form:

```
<?php echo form_open('state/validate_rejection/'.$file_results->sender_id.'/'.$this->session->userdata('id').'/'.$file_results->id, array('name'=>'rejection_form', 'id'=>'rejection_form', 'onsubmit'=>'window.forms[0].submit();self.close();')); ?>
```

```
<p>
    <label>Write the reason of Rejection?<span class='req'>* Required</label>
    <textarea name="remarks" rows="8"  max-width:380px " autofocus required></textarea>
</p>
```

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="cancel"  />
<input name="submit_rejection" id="submit_rejection" type="submit" class="button" value="Send" />
```

as you can see the form action is a url that goes to a controller/method :
here is the method i use:

```
function validate_rejection(){
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('remarks', 'Remarks', 'trim|required');
     if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
         $sender_id = $this->uri->segment(3) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
         $user_id = $this->uri->segment(4) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
         $file_id = $this->uri->segment(5) ? $this->uri->segment(5) : 0;
    //here a function from codigniter model is called, and returns true if query succeded, false if it failed
         $rejection = $this->files_model->reject_file($sender_id, $user_id, $file_id);

         if($rejection == TRUE){

             $this->session->set_flashdata('rejection_succ', 'Rejected Successfully');
             //redirect('home');
         }
         else{
              $this->session->set_flashdata('rejection_fail', 'Rejection of file Failed');
         }
      }
      else{
           $this->session->set_flashdata('remarks_validation_errors', validation_errors());
      }
  }
```

nd if the form is submitted successfully or failed it will set a flashdata

NOW I WANT THAT WHEN THE FORM IS SUBMITTED TO CHECK IF FORM IS FINISHED, RELOAD THE PARENT PAGE AND CLOSE THE POPUP….
Can anyone please help me achieve that…it is also a javascript case, but as long as i am working with codeigniter i thought that this will be the best place to post this thread?

note: sorry for bad formatting...im a new user and i didnt see code blocks :S

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use jQuery Dialog - http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form .Why reinventing warm water if it already exist. The only thing you will have to add is to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

After submitting form successfully & setting flashdata add following line to your controller/method that

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.close();window.opener.top.location.reload();</script>";
```